# is Java HostSpotVM option"-XX:+UseSingleJNICriticalLock"　correct?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, weblogic

Now, I'm trying to find information about what the title of this post.
but I couldn't find it.
"-XX:+UseSingleJNICriticalLock" is correct option?

best regerds

Comment: Where did you see that option?

Comment: thanks for your response. I saw this in some scripts which is working regacy system. architectural documents are nothing. that script seems be working when weblogic server start or stop.

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding, I couldn't see something similar to 'UseSingleJNICriticalLoc' in options on Java HotSpot VM Options page.[Java HotSpot VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Comment: thanks for your opinion. I think so. there isn't this option or similar things on page what you have shown. but I just get latest information.this option written by auther as a way for aboiding hungup. auther seems followed advise of weblogic-support and HP-supprt. is this option unopened for normal customer?